# 403 after Ruby on Rails Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http-status-code-403

Ruby and Rails is already set up but I always get a 403 on visiting the "localhost"
Got no errors on setup a new rails proect. This is my 'bundle install'
Any missing? There should be the welcome aboard site but i get the 403. When i surf to localhost/public i get the welcome aboard site.

```
    Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.5) 
Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
Using execjs (1.3.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.3) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.3) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Using rails (3.2.3) 
Using sass (3.1.18) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using uglifier (1.2.4)
```

I tried to create new view and controller with `$ rails generate controller home index` 
and changed my routes.rb to home#index. I also get a 403.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
rails server -p 3001 -e test
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in test on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-05-18 10:50:16] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-05-18 10:50:16] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-05-18 10:50:16] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=26471 port=3001
```

On browsing to the site nothing happens. Only get a apache 403 forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running ...

```
rails server
```

in you root application directory?

Sounds like the web server isn't running?

Comment: yes i tried it with and without the `rails server` Did also a `rake db:create` before

Comment: im using on a subdomain of my domain. So I browse to this subdomain and get the 403. If I use subdomain:3000 I get a connection error.

Comment: Can you post the log from your web server window from when you start rails server and try and access a page

Comment: Server starts as expected. Not getting any followup messages on surfing to the site. See my edit

Comment: Im using it on the web. So i go on sub.domain.com

Comment: Ok, I'm totally confused now. I think you may need to start from scratch with the instructions for setting up a new site on your local machine at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails.  Follow the instructions on that page exactly then if you still have issues shout.

Comment: I have rails installed on my vhost on the web... i can call it with a sub.domain.com. Controlling it with ssh and sshfs.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well in that case if it's not a vhost already setup for Rails then you will need to install a webserver such as passenger, http://www.modrails.com/install.html